# How to create Employee Attendance List / Report using SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list, sharepoint-foundation

I want to create company employee attendance sheet using SharePoint OOTB web part or List. Can any one please provide some good example or link which I can refer please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first create a new content type with name Attendance. The content type should have minimum following site columns

1. Employee Number (This will be the unique id which can identify the employee
2. Date (This will be the date value which indicate the employee has worked on that date or not)

You can add more relevant fields like department or total hours worked for the date etc.

Next create a custom list and using advanced property set the content type you created above.

You can done with the setup. Now users or manager can start filling in the list.

References

[Creating new content type](http://www.petri.com/create-new-content-type-sharepoint-2013.htm)

[Creating custom list](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/create-list-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

[Adding content type to the list](https://support.office.com/en-CA/Article/Add-a-content-type-to-a-list-or-library-917366ae-f7a2-47ad-87a5-9689a1884e60)

Comment: Thanks Amal,This is really helpfull. I'm planing to create one employee directory / Employee Details like ID,Name,Department,Phone etc. Now after that I will create one attendance list where once will pull few details of employee and only user need to enter in and out time daily or weekly & it will show total number of hours worked in per week. Any attendance list example if you provide it will be great (I've already refer your above provided link and its really helpful l to start but if you provide some link which is for attendance it will be great). Thanks for again for your valuable comment